# Скачивание файла wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте есть форма, которая сохраняет вводные данные в файл, на странице с документацикй есть ссылка для скачивания этого файла, но после тооо как пересадил сайт с локального на хостинг, файл так же скачивается, но с данными из локального сервера.
Мой сайт на вордпрессе и на странице с докумертацией стоит хук get_template_directory_uri(). Если смотреть на хостинге то данрые добавляются, но при скачивании через фронтенд новых данных нет.

Comment: имя домена в ссылке на скачивание верное? похоже, что там `http://localhost/...`

Comment: Либо вы залили этот файл так же как и остальные (с данными, оставшимися от localhost), либо они у вас закэшировались. Попробуйте запросить с любым случайным параметром в адресной строке, очистить кэш браузера, либо открыть из под Инкогнито.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Answer (score 0):

Вам отдается закешированный файл из-за совпадения имени.

Попробуйте в ссылку с файлом добавить с уникальное значение - например, время в секундах.

```
название_файла?<?php echo time(); ?>
```